# mongodb get all subdocuments from all documents

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, mongodb

I have this sample documents

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("549452820d56c14be9473f30"),
  "company" : "google",
  "customers" : [{
      "cart" : "34323",
      "logins" : [{
          "Id" : 1,
          "Date" : ISODate("2013-02-21T12:54:52Z"),
        }, {
          "Id" : 2,
          "Date" : ISODate("2013-02-21T12:55:10Z"),
        }]
    }]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("549452820d56c14be9473f31"),
  "company" : "microsoft",
  "customers" : [{
      "cart" : "14423",
      "logins" : [{
          "Id" : 6,
          "Date" : ISODate("2013-02-21T12:58:09Z"),
        }, {
          "Id" : 7,
          "Date" : ISODate("2013-02-21T12:57:50Z"),
        }, {
          "Id" : 8,
          "Date" : ISODate("2013-02-21T12:58:18Z"),
        }]
    }]
}
```

1. I would like to know how I can, for instance, get all the logins from all costumers in both `Linq` and js language (if it's possible). This should be pretty simple but I'm just not getting it. The trick here is that I would like the query only to return me the logins data without the rest of the document fields...
2. I also would like to know how I could get a whole document based on the "cart" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below Mongo queries may help you.

```
db.test.find({},{"customers.logins":true,_id:false})
```

will return login details alone.

```
db.test.find({"customers.cart":"34323"})
```

will get a whole document based on the "cart" property.